# logback file name format including time format

Tags: java, logback

In my project we are using logback for logging.Currently we are rolling the file
based on the completion of day or it reached 10 MB.

Below is my configuration.

```
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>/archived/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="com.example.RollOnStartupAndSizeTriggeringPolicy">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </TimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
```

Currently file format is like below in archieved folder.

```
 error.2019-07-19.0
 error.2019-07-19.1
 error.2019-07-19.2
```

But we need a file format like below

```
 error.2019-07-19 11:00:00
 error.2019-07-19 11:05:00
```

If I change the file format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss every second the logback is created. But I want the rotation
    should happen in day or it reached 10 MB.

I tried to use aux but using that I can able to create the folder only.

```
<fileNamePattern>
    /archived/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm, aux}/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
</fileNamePattern>
```

Is there any way to keep the file format like below. But the file should rotate for every day or 10 MB

error.2019-07-19 11:00:00.log

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in configuration

```
<timestamp key="bySecond" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss" 
          timeReference="contextBirth"/>
```

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

Also follow this link in case of any collision https://logback.qos.ch/codes.html

Comment: It will generate the file for every second. I need the rotation should happen only if it is reached 10 MB or the compeletion of day