# Gatling log files not getting generated for my logback.xml

Tags: scala, logback, gatling

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{15} - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
    </appender>

    <timestamp key="timestamp" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"/>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>logs/test_${timestamp}.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{15} - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

<!--     Uncomment for logging ALL HTTP request and responses-->
        <logger name="io.gatling.http.ahc" level="TRACE" />
        <logger name="io.gatling.http.response" level="TRACE" />
<!--     Uncomment for logging ONLY FAILED HTTP request and responses-->
<!--        <logger name="io.gatling.http.ahc" level="DEBUG" />-->
<!--        <logger name="io.gatling.http.response" level="DEBUG" />-->
<!--     TRACE logs all HTTP requests/response, DEBUG logs only failed HTTP requests/response-->
<!--      <logger name="io.gatling.http.engine.response" level="DEBUG" />-->


    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
<!--        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>-->
    </root>

</configuration>
```

[image]

**Only simulation.log and gatling report got generated. but it should generate logs/test_${timestamp}.log file as per logback config. Can anyone help on this?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267242/logback-file-name-format-including-time-format. And I think it is not related to Scala and to gatling. Can you add logback tag?

Comment: Thanks, added logback tag. Also above link is for file name format change

Comment: still looking for solution to get generate log files

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the log file is generated where you expect it? Have you tried setting an absolute path?

Comment: No, still looking for solution to get generate log files. You mean mentioning exact path to store log file? Absolute path wont work for gitlab runner right?